# Google maps api v3 marker list and jQuery

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3

I am using Google Maps API v3 and it's working great, however I want to add a class when I hover over my marker list but I can't seem to access it via jQuery. Is there anyway I can get around this?

My jQuery:

```
$('ul#marker_list li').hover(function(){
   $(this).addClass('selected');
}, function(){
   $(this).removeClass('selected');
});
```

Google maps api code

```
side_bar_html += '<li><a href="javascript:myclick(' + (gmarkers.length-1) + ')" ref="' + (gmarkers.length-1) + '">' + name + '<\/a></li>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the `:hover` selector in CSS?

```
ul#marker_list li:hover {
    // whatever style you want a hovered over marker to look like
}
```

Comment: After reading your question again, do you mean you want the marker on the map to get a different style if you hover over the link in the list?

Comment: Yes that is right, I don't want to use :hover as I need to add a class because the colour is generated dynamically.